# Dart - HTTP - Encode JSON Object with Array & int properties

Tags: http, dart, dart-io

I'm trying to make a POST request using dart's http package with json data as the body, I'm using a variable of type dynamic to create the json object and so far it works perfectly as long as all the values in the object are strings.

If I assign the value of a property to be an `int` or `List<int>` (expecting it to be converted to an array, as expected by the server) dart crashes due to expecting either a `Map<String, String>` or a `List<int>` as the type for the body (the exact type it expects is dynamic, but it tries to cast it to `Map<String, String>` or `List<int>`).

My question is, is there any workaround to making a http POST request in dart using a object with dynamic property values?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the `HttpClient` & `HttpClientRequest` classes from the `dart:io` package.

I stored the body as a `Map<String, dynamic>` and json encoded it before writing it to the request stream.